mavenBom from spring dependency-management Gradle plugin does not add bom to gradle module file
I have a simple library project A and I use spring dependency management.
dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("io.grpc:grpc-bom:$grpcBomVersion")
            mavenBom("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-bom:$protobufBomVersion")
        }
    }

Generated pom file fot this project is ok, but generated gradle 'module' file, which is used by default if I import my project A into project B does not contain following code snippet:
"dependencies": [
        {
          "group": "io.grpc",
          "module": "grpc-bom",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.58.0"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "org.gradle.category": "platform"
          },
          "endorseStrictVersions": true
        },
        {
          "group": "com.google.protobuf",
          "module": "protobuf-bom",
          "version": {
            "requires": "3.24.0"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "org.gradle.category": "platform"
          },
          "endorseStrictVersions": true
        },

This behavior causes that** I need to manually add boms to project B**(project B imports library project A):
 implementation(platform("io.grpc:grpc-bom:$grpcBomVersion")) implementation(platform("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-bom:$protobufBomVersion"))
if I use platform for library project A:
implementation(platform("io.grpc:grpc-bom:$grpcBomVersion"))
implementation(platform("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-bom:$protobufBomVersion"))

then all is ok, generated gradle .module file contains mentioned lines:
"dependencies": [
        {
          "group": "io.grpc",
          "module": "grpc-bom",
          "version": {
            "requires": "1.58.0"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "org.gradle.category": "platform"
          },
          "endorseStrictVersions": true
        },
        {
          "group": "com.google.protobuf",
          "module": "protobuf-bom",
          "version": {
            "requires": "3.24.0"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "org.gradle.category": "platform"
          },
          "endorseStrictVersions": true
        },

So no need to manually import boms to  project B(project B imports library project A):
 implementation(platform("io.grpc:grpc-bom:$grpcBomVersion")) implementation(platform("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-bom:$protobufBomVersion"))
But I don't like to use platform gradle notation in project A, cause in this case I have different versions of same transitive dependencies in project A. I don't want to exclude them manually. When I use dependency-management plugin in project A - I see that my duplicates of transitive dependencies are gone , so prefer to use dependency-management plugin instead of platform, but it causes missed boms in generated gradle .module file

This is not possible with the Spring Dependency Management plugin. See the following issue for details: https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/342

thank you! finally to achieve both bom info in gradle module + omit transitive dependencies duplicate we decided to use both dependency management + platform for grpc boms in Library project A:
apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management") // to remove transitive lib duplicates
api(platform("io.grpc:grpc-bom:$grpcBomVersion")) //for bom info into generated gradle module
